# Verifying if a string (several words) in an array of strings matches with another string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner in ruby. I have an array of strings like this ["a b c", "d e f"] and I have a string like this "xapqbrc". I want to verify if "xapqbrc" contains all the words in each string but not necessarily one next to other. How can I do that in ruby?

```
["a b c", "d e f"].include? "xapqbrc"
```

is not working as expected

Comment: By "all the words in each string" do you mean "all the letters"? So it would match the first, but not the second?

Answer (score 1):

[`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) just checks if any object equals any object in the Array. `["a b c", "d e f"].include? "xapqbrc"` would only be true if the whole string `"xapqbrc"` was in the Array.

Splitting this into two parts, first checking if one string contains all the words in another. First, [split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-split) the string of words up into an Array.

```
words = "a b c".split(/ /)  # ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Now we can use `include?` but on a String to check if the String contains another string. `"food".include?("foo")` is true. But that's only for one word, we need to do this for all words. Use `all?` to check if a thing is true for all items in an Array.

```
words.all? { |word| "xapqbrc".include?(word) }
```

Finally, we need to do this for an Array of those words. We can use [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-select) to get only the items in the Array for which the block is true.

```
# ["a b c"]
matches = ["a b c", "d e f"].select { |string|
  words = string.split(/ /)

  # The last statement in the block determines the truthiness of the block.
  words.all? { |word| "xapqbrc".include?(word) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if all characters in a string occur in the arrays of strings:

```
('xapqbrc'.chars - ['a b c', 'd e f'].map(&:chars).flatten).empty?
# => false
```

Here is a breakdown of the above statement.
The method [`chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chars) returns the array of all characters in a string. Note that for a string with blanks, this array will include blanks. If you want to extract the characters **separated** by blanks, or, more generally, whitespace, use [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) like so (as in the answer by *Schwern*):

`['a b c', 'd e f'].map{ |s| s.split(/ /) }.flatten`

The method [`flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) takes the array of arrays and flattens it into a single array.

```
puts 'xapqbrc'.chars.inspect
# => ["x", "a", "p", "q", "b", "r", "c"]

puts ['a b c', 'd e f'].map(&:chars).flatten.inspect
# => ["a", " ", "b", " ", "c", "d", " ", "e", " ", "f"]

puts ('xapqbrc'.chars - ['a b c', 'd e f'].map(&:chars).flatten).inspect
# => ["x", "p", "q", "r"]

puts ('xapqbrc'.chars - ['a b c', 'd e f'].map(&:chars).flatten).empty?
# => false
```

A few more examples:

```
strings1 = ['a b c', 'd e f']

['xapqbrc', 'accbbb', 'xpq', ' ', ''].each do |string2|
  puts "string2=#{string2};"
  puts (string2.chars - strings1.map(&:chars).flatten).empty?
end

# => string2=xapqbrc;
# => false
# => string2=accbbb;
# => true
# => string2=xpq;
# => false
# => string2= ;
# => true
# => string2=;
# => true
```